# set footer in all printed pages using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

**What I want to achieve:**

I am currently using PHPExcel and I want to display the filename and the page numbers in ***all the right hand side footer of all the printed pages***.

Basically the format should be

```
filename.xlsx Page 1 / 2
```

where `filename.xlsx` is the file name

and 1 is the current page number

and 2 is the total page number

**What I have tried:**

I have tried the following code:

```
$this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&R&F');
$this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&R&P');
$this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&R&N');
```

On the print preview we saw there are 5 sheets

When we press print, the printer printed out 4 only.

- First page we only see the filename
- Second page we only see the number 4
- Third page we only see the number 5
- Fourth page we only see the number 4

The position is correct in all the pages, ie the right hand side footer.

The value is not.

Please advise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need the footer displayed on all pages, then you need to save the value for odd and for even footers

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&R&F Page &P / &N');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()->setEvenFooter('&R&F Page &P / &N');
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of copying your footer configuration you can do this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()->setDifferentOddEven(false);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&R&F Page &P / &N');
```