# PHPExcel - get current page during document creation

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Client works in pharmacy industry.

We print bills for items bought by clients.

General structure of document is the following:

```
Header
List of items
Footer
```

Sometimes happens such situation when all list of items fit into N number of pages.

In this case footer is moved to the last page.

Local law forbids such documents, i.e.footer cannot be alone. It needs contain at least one sold position.

**Thoughts about implementation:**

It would be easy to implement it if I could get the current page during the calling operations like setCellValue or fromArray.

In this case I could check how many lines I still have and if I'm on the new page.
If I 'm on the new page and have zero items then I would add empty line before last position.

I feel it's not possible to get in phpexcel because of the way how Excel works at all.

As for now I have in my mind only one dirty solution:
  creating document upon user request
 -> storing in somewhere to temporary folder on server  -> reading it and checking if document has last page without items , if this is the case I would add empty position  and recreate document again (some kind recursion with limited depth.)

But this is too messy solution. Are there any better ways to handle such problem?

Comment: By "page" do you mean Excel Worksheets or actual paper pages when printing ?

Comment: actual pages when printing - e.g. http://kagda.ru/i/de011358de724_28-06-2017-09:58:21_de01.png

Comment: Header and Footer like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/19241635/367456 ?

Comment: yes, exactly. The only difference is I want to get it into variable for further analysis  like $pageCurrent=  $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->gettOddFooter('&P'); . Unfortunately this is just pseudo code

Answer (score 2):

Actually if the format is fixed in which you print hopefully (like font type and size, header format, paper size etc) then You can check how many rows are there:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
//if 0 is the sheet you are working on
```

You can check how many rows does it require to push the `footer` to a new page. Basically there is a formula to you:

```
$footerWillBeOnSeparateSheet = $allRowCount % $maximumRowPerPage === $nomberOfRowsWhenFooterGetsOnTheNextPage;
```

If `$footerWillBeOnSeparateSheet` is true then you need to add the empty row you mentioned.

I'd use a different approach instead of adding an empty line. Try to separate the last two items and footer for example into a different page in case the value of `$footerWillBeOnSeparateSheet` is true.

***Edit:*** using `getRowHeight()` is also an option although it would be hard to maintain the differences of the different templates.

Comment: Ehh, it would be really cool if all rows were fixed in height. Unfortunately sometimes name of position or its producer (or another column but probability is much lower) can get extremely large - about 350 symbols  and it takes more space than usually.  This is how it looks in practice  -http://kagda.ru/i/6e0110916e95_28-06-2017-14:25:56_6e01.png  .

Comment: Probably I can develop this idea further and make some calculations  (in advance on paper in manually mode)how many lines will take string having N symbols , let's say that line with  200 symbols ttakes -  2 lines, with 300 symbols - 3 lines . In such case it's possible to calculate total number of lines. But I  feel  that such solution smells.... If I were a builder I wouldn't stand under such bridge   to prove that bridge works. still upvote, thanks for spending your time

Comment: This case you should iterate through the rows and use `getRowHeight()` and sum all of it. This way you'll be able to calculate more precisely. (I do not know if there is any function to get the actual sum height but it is a workaround to sum everything.) If I have some time later I'll check it for you.

Comment: I doubt in accuracy of this method ,so probably not worth even to try to invest time into it

Comment: It is basically the same idea based on pixels/points instead of the number of rows. This way you can determine a range and do the same, but it is way harder than the row number approach.

Comment: accuracy will suffer.  Plus every document will need to have its own constant settings (related the height what can takes rows on the first page, on middle page, on last page probably smth else) which you need to keep up to date with every style change ). Rules out approach

Comment: True. But if the header is added to the file itself it would be counted as well.